# Dagger2 Build issue- cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am new to Dagger 2 and has been making some good progress until recently. I have a fragment `CalculatorFragment` which unloads all of the logic into it's `Presenter` class, which has an interface `ViewOps` as it's constructor that is already implemented by `CalculatorFragment`.

#### CalculatorFragment.java

```
public class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment implements ViewOps {
    @Inject PresenterOps Presenter

    public View onCreateView(...){
        //...

        CalculatorApplication
            .getApplicationComponent(getActivity())
            .getCalculatorFinancialComponent(new CalculatorModule(this))
            .inject(this);

        //...
    }
```

Everything was working fine until I decided to move the update display functions into a separate class and tried to inject it back into the `Presenter`. The `UpdateDisplay` class takes the same `ViewOps` as a constructor.

#### Presenter.java

```
public class Presenter implements PresenterOps{
    @Inject TextFunctions textFunctions;
    @Inject ConversionFunctions conversionFunctions;

    //ADDING THIS INJECT ANNOTATION CAUSED THE PROBLEM!!!
    @Inject UpdateDisplay updateDisplay;

    public Presenter(ViewOps viewOps) {
        CalculatorApplication
        .getApplicationComponent(getActivity()).inject(this);
    }

    public someFunctions(){
       textFunctions.doSomething();  
       conversionFunctions.doSomething(); 
       updateDisplay.doSomething();    
    }
}
```

My understanding with Dagger 2 is I need to create a module class that defines the methods that will create the dependencies to be injected. The problem below is with the method `providesUpdateDisplay()`. Everytime I build the project, it calls out the following error:

> Error:(21, 10) error: UpdateDisplay cannot be provided without an
>   @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated
>   method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly
>   provided.

I thought I already provided an `@Provides providesUpdateDisplay()` annotated method in the `CalculatorModule` below.

#### CalculatorModule.java

```
@Module
public class CalculatorModule {

    private CalculatorFragment calculatorFragment;

    public CalculatorModule(CalculatorFragment calculatorFragment) {
        this.calculatorFragment = calculatorFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    ViewOps providesViewOps() {
        return calculatorFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    CalculatorFragment providesCalculatorFinancial() {
        return calculatorFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    PresenterOps providesPresenterOps() {
        return new Presenter(calculatorFragment);
    }

    //ISN'T THIS SUPPOSE TO BE THE @Provides method 
    //THAT PROVIDES UpdateDisplay???
    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    UpdateDisplay providesUpdateDisplay() {
        return new UpdateDisplay(calculatorFragment);
    }
}
```

To add, if I do not do `@Inject UpdateDisplay updateDisplay`, and simply create an instance of `UpdateDisplay` in the `Presenter` constructor and not injecting `UpdateDislay` into the `AppComponent`, then everything works back OK.

```
public Presenter(ViewOps viewOps) {
    new UpdateDisplay(getViewOps());
}
```

The problem is I cannot simply call injection of `UpdateDisplay` into the `Presenter` that I want to.

Here's the `UpdateDisplay`:

#### UpdateDisplay.java

```
    public class UpdateDisplay {
        @Inject ConversionFunctions conversionFunctions;

        private final ViewOps viewOps;

        public UpdateDisplay(ViewOps viewOps) {
            CalculatorApplication
            .getApplicationComponent(viewOps.getActivity())
            .inject(this);
            this.viewOps = viewOps;
        }

        public doSomething() {
           //...
        }
```

#### CalculatorApplication

```
public class CalculatorApplication extends Application {
    private AppComponent component;

    public static AppComponent getApplicationComponent(Context context) {
        return ((CalculatorApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).component;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }
}
```

These are the components:

#### AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(ActivityMain activityMain);
    CalculatorComponent getCalculatorFinancialComponent(CalculatorModule module);
    void inject(UpdateDisplay updateDisplay);
    void inject(Presenter presenter);
}
```

#### CalculatorComponent.java

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {CalculatorModule.class})
public interface CalculatorComponent {
    void inject(CalculatorFinancial calculatorFinancial);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using field injection? I just wrote an answer the other day about how to _not_ use it for reference. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779883/1837367

Comment: Your error seems to be because you try to inject `UpdateDisplay` in `@Singleton` scope but you provide it in `@ActivityScope`, so Dagger has no way to access the provides method. If this is the error, please close as duplicate for future reference. If it is not please include the *full error* as shown in the question.