# View not being instantiated by Dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm doing a Dagger study project and I'm doing this based on some other projects I found in git, I'm having a problem in a class.

The project is about reading and submitting git repositories, it came to work without using MVP and Dagger but I'm refactoring it to use these features.

The RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl class that extends a BasePresenter  which in turn has a View that is of BaseView type (IRepositoriePopMVPView also has an extend that is BaseView) has a getView method that accesses the methods that control some functions in the View, account of the needs of the MVP concept.

The problem is that in the RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl when I call the getView is speaking that this null, when I debug I saw that the View is really null but I can not understand why. The project has many other classes and I will post here the ones that are related to the problem, if anyone can help me.

**DIRepositorieModulo**

```
@Module
public class DIRepositorieModulo {

    private IRepositoriePopMVPView mView;
    private RepositoriesPopPopAdapter mAdapter;

    public DIRepositorieModulo(IRepositoriePopMVPView view, RepositoriesPopPopAdapter adapter) {
        this.mView = view;
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @PerActivityScope
    @Provides
    IRepositorieAPI provideApiServiceRepositorie(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(IRepositorieAPI.class);
    }



    @PerActivityScope
    @Provides
    IRepositoriePopMVPView provideView(){
        return mView;
    }


    @PerActivityScope
    @Provides
    IRepositoriePopAdapterMVPModel provideRepositorieAdapterMVPModel(){
        return mAdapter;
    }



    @PerActivityScope
    @Provides
    IRepositoriePopAdapterMVPView provideRepositorieAdapterMVPView(){
        return mAdapter;
    }



    @PerActivityScope
    @Provides
    RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl provideRepositoriePresenter(){
        return new RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl();
    }

}
```

**BaseView**

```
public interface BaseView {

}
```

**IRepositoriePopMVPView *extends* BaseView**

```
public interface IRepositoriePopMVPView extends BaseView {

    void listRepositories(List<Item> listItem);

    void checkedUnCheckedRepoFavorite();
    void onShowMessage(String message);
    void callDetailRepositorie(Item item);

    void onHideMessage();

    void onShowProgress(String message);
    void onHideProgress();

    void onShowToast(String message);

    void refresh();

}
```

**RepositoriesPopFragment *extends* BaseFragment *implements* IRepositoriePopMVPView**

```
public class RepositoriesPopFragment extends BaseFragment implements IRepositoriePopMVPView {

    public static final String FRAG_POP = "fragPop";

    private Unbinder mUnbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_pop_repo_java)
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerRepositories;

    protected RepositoriesPopPopAdapter mAdapter;

    @Inject
    protected IRepositoriePopAdapterMVPView mAdapterView;

    @Inject
    protected RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl mPresenter;

    private View view = null;

    @Override
    protected void onViewReady(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
        super.onViewReady(savedInstanceState, intent);
        initializeRecyclerRepositorie();
        mPresenter.getRepositories();
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerRepositorie() {
        mRecyclerRepositories.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerRepositories.setLayoutManager(llm);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pop_repo_java, container, false);
        }
        mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);     
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    protected void resolverDaggerDependecy() {

        mAdapter = new RepositoriesPopPopAdapter(getContext());

        DaggerDIRepositorieComponent
                .builder()
                .dIRepositorieModulo(new DIRepositorieModulo(this, mAdapter))
                .dIApplicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
                .build().injectFragment(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void listRepositories(List<Item> listItem) {
        Log.i("app", "RepositoriesPopFragment - listRepositories - listItem Size" + listItem.size());
        mRecyclerRepositories.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setListRepositore(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void callDetailRepositorie(Item item) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NOME " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        DetailRepositoriesFragment frag = new DetailRepositoriesFragment(item.getOwner().getLogin(), item.getName());
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, frag, DetailRepositoriesFragment.FRAG_DETAIL_REPO);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(DetailRepositoriesFragment.FRAG_DETAIL_REPO);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkedUnCheckedRepoFavorite() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onHideMessage() {
        hideMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowProgress(String message) {
        if(message!=null || !message.isEmpty()){
            showProgress(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideProgress() {
        hideProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowMessage(String message) {
        showMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowToast(String message) {
        showToast(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        mAdapterView.refresh();
    }
}
```

**BasePresenter < V *extends* BaseView >**

```
public class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> {

    @Inject
    protected V mView;

    //Fornece a View para realizar as operações do MVP
    protected V getView() {
        return mView;
    }

    protected <T> void subscribe(Observable<T> observable, Observer<T> observer){
        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .toSingle()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer);
    }

}
```

**RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl *extends* BasePresenter < IRepositoriePopMVPView >**

```
public class RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl extends BasePresenter<IRepositoriePopMVPView> implements Observer<Repositories>{

    @Inject
    protected IRepositorieAPI mApiService;


    @Inject
    public RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl(){
    }

    public void getRepositories() {
        getView().onShowProgress("Carregando Repositórios");
        Observable<Repositories> repositoriesObservable = mApiService.getAllRepositories();
        subscribe(repositoriesObservable, this);
    }

    //Todo: Methods implementation of Observer<Repositories>
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        getView().onHideProgress();
        getView().onShowToast("Repositórios carregados!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        getView().onHideProgress();
        getView().onHideMessage();
        getView().onShowMessage("Não foi possível carregar os Repositórios");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Repositories repositories) {
        List<Item> listItem = repositories.getItems();
        if(listItem!=null){
            getView().listRepositories(repositories.getItems());
        }else{
            getView().onShowMessage("Não foi possível carregar os Repositórios");
        }
    }
}
```

> 10-23 15:45:05.772 1972-1972/gitrepopop
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: gitrepopop, PID: 1972
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {gitrepopop/gitrepopop.MVP.Main.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   gitrepopop.MVP.Repositorie.IRepositoriePopMVPView.onShowProgress(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3509)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'void
>   gitrepopop.MVP.Repositorie.IRepositoriePopMVPView.onShowProgress(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at
>   gitrepopop.MVP.Repositorie.RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl.getRepositories(**RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl.java**:27)
>                                                                                         at
>   gitrepopop.MVP.Repositorie.RepositoriesPopFragment.onViewReady(**RepositoriesPopFragment.java**:69)
>                                                                                         at
>   gitrepopop.MVP.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(**BaseFragment.java**:36)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:499)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6812)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3509) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)

Comment: Please consider using constructor injection. There was a question a couple of days ago basically the same as yours, see here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779883/1837367

Answer (score 0):

But RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl, extends BasePresenter that has a Generic of . as IRepositoriePopMVPView extends from BaseView it means that the getView method of BasePresenter accesses the view of the  which is my Fragment, RepositoriesPopFragment. The way you explained in the other topic I should pass as a parameter in the RepositoriesPopPresenterImpl constructor.

I would use java generic! I use these two repositories as a study: 
http://github.com/filippella/Dagger-Rx-Database-MVP http://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture